# How to load a json that returns inside a jquery tag?

Tags: python, jquery, json

After making a request to a url it returns me a "json"

```
jQuery18106653279830000903({
    "Items":[
        {"Contacts":[],"Images":[],"Files":[],"Error":false,"Date":"11/29/2019","MessageText":"", ...}, 
        {"Contacts":[], ...},
        ...], 
    "Error":false})
```

The big number after "jQuery" changes for every request. (Not sure what it means or how it's determined, but if anyone can shed a light I'd appreciate)

I'm using scrapy and usually I would just do this `result = json.loads(response.body)` and would work with as a dict. However, due to that jQuery tag(?)/data(?)/object(?) attached it raises

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I can make it work using regex, however I would like to know if there is another way to do it? Clearly I have no clue about JS/jQuery and this may have a more objective/pythonic solution.

Comment: Just strip off that outer shell to leave the JSON object inside; load that.  I'm not clear where this is a problem for you ... explain?

Comment: How exactly do you make the request, to which server? Ideally a server should be sending JSON or stringified JSON, this seems to be a function call

Comment: That response is JSONP formatted, not JSON. You need to therefore specify JSONP as the dataType in the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: @Prune As I said, I can handle the issue, would like to know if there is another way, like a proper parser for this kind of return (that it's not [completely] a json).

Comment: Thanks; I understand now.  It appears that @RoryMcCrossan has you covered.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava It's a GET request, with the number as query string. I retrieved from the original page HTML and couldn't figure out how it's generated.